# LSTM fails to learn with TensorFlow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I played with this simple LSTM network, but the MSE is too high after training. What could be the problem?

Sequence input: array([3553, 3554, 3542, 3518, 3484, 3440, 3386, 3325, 3256, 3181, 3101,
       3016, 2928, 2836, 2742, 2647, 2551, 2454, 2357, 2261, 2165, 2071,
       1978])
The training sequence has a length of 4 periods, and 1 feature for each period.
Data is zero-padded and reshaped to (-1,4,1)

Preprocessing:

```
lst=np.array([3553, 3554, 3542, 3518, 3484, 3440, 3386, 3325, 3256, 3181, 3101,
   3016, 2928, 2836, 2742, 2647, 2551, 2454, 2357, 2261, 2165, 2071,
   1978])
X=[]
y=[]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
    X.append(lst[max(0,i-4):i])
    y.append(lst[i])

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
X=pad_sequences(X).reshape(-1,4,1)
y=np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
```

Model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1,input_shape=(4,1), batch_size=2,stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(2,stateful=True,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(2,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="adam")
history=model.fit(X,y,epochs=4000,verbose=0)
plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
```

The MSE image:

[image]
What's the problem that makes LSTM not learning anything? Not enough data? Not enough training epochs?

Comment: Epochs are extremely much. Data is too varied and not enough. Increase the network architecture too

Comment: @celius-stingher Thanks, but that's all the data that I've got. What do you mean by epochs are extremely much?